# NGINX Rewriting Question

Tags: apache, nginx

How would I convert the following Apache rule

```
RewriteRule ^watch/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ watch.php?v=$1 [NC]
```

into the appropriate format for an NGINX configuration file?

Further edit:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    root /var/www/ROOT;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

        return 302 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;

    location / {
        #
        # HIDE PHP EXTENSION
        #
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }


    location /watch.php {
        rewrite ^/watch/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /watch.php?v=$1;
    }

    #
    # HIDE PHP EXTENSION
    #
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    #
    # BLOCK REFERRER URLS
    #

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 401 /error_pages/401.php;
    error_page 403 /error_pages/403.php;
    error_page 404 /error_pages/404.php;
    error_page 405 /error_pages/405.php;
    error_page 408 /error_pages/408.php;

    location ^~ /error/ {
        internal;
        root /error_pages/;
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the `nginx` server configuration block.

Comment: You have a `return 302` which should not be there. And the `location /watch.php` should be `location /watch`. And you should probably stick a `last` modifier on the end of the `rewrite`.

Comment: What is the recommended way to force HTTPS, I know in Apache it can be done with the following 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

Comment: Now I can access the page at http://www.domain-name.tld/watch/1 but not http://www.domain-name.tld/watch?v=1, I would like to have it accessible via both if it is possible

Comment: Use two separate `server` blocks see [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom)

Comment: Change the location to `location /watch/ { ... }`

Comment: I tried changing it to /watch/ { ... } but now it downloads an empty file for /watch?v=1 rather than a not found error

Comment: Try moving the rewrite into the `location /` block and deleting the `location /watch/` block.

Comment: I got it to work with the following:

location /watch { rewrite ^/watch$ /watch.php?v=$1; }
location /watch/ { rewrite ^/watch/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /watch.php?v=$1; }

Thanks Richard :)

Comment: Ok, I have tested your configuration with just a single `location /watch/` and it works for both the `/watch/1` and `/watch?v=1` cases.

Comment: I like Apache for its ease of use but I decided to try NGINX mainly for the learning experience and to see if it would give me any benefits over Apache other than the speed difference with serving static content

Comment: I just changed it to a single location /watch/ and it started downloading the page as a file with no extension again which is confusing because it works with both location blocks and it worked for you with a single location block but is incorrect on my configuration :/

Comment: There's a bit of a learning curve - I use [this site](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) for documentation.

Comment: There's not a file called `watch` lying around in your docroot is there?

Comment: No, just the watch.php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33528/discussion-between-richard-smith-and-itteam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI in `nginx` includes the leading `/`, so the equivalent rewrite would be:

```
location /watch/ {
    rewrite ^/watch/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /watch.php?v=$1 last;
}
```

> Would that go in the location / { } block?

That is a slightly more complicated question, and it depends on the `nginx` configuration, particularly what other `location` blocks exist.

The options are:

- Place it near the top of the `server` container (outside a `location`
  block)
- Place it in the `/` location
- Place it in a `/watch` location

Comment: Would that go in the location / { } block? Because when I try it and browse to the page it just downloads the page into my downloads folder with no file extension

Comment: @itteam Does your configuration support PHP files?

Comment: @itteam I just realised that the other place to stick it is above the `rewrite` in the `@extensionless-php` location block (as long as they all have a `last` modifier).

Comment: Ok, I will try that, I don't think there would be much difference between Apache & NGINX for me anyway as my pages only use simple PHP includes for items like the footer and navigation bars